# Multiple rows entry @ Textarea, Explode and remove space at end

Tags: php, html

following problem:

I want to do the following:

Each line has a space at the end, except the last one.

this somehow makes the usage of the api unusable. I tried some functions, but probably wrong.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $text=explode("\n",$_POST["urls"]);
    foreach ($text as $line) {
        $api_url = "http://api.url/api?api=ftJRl2JJ4wLX&url=".$line;
        $res = @json_decode(file_get_contents($api_url),TRUE);
        echo $res["msg"];
        echo "<br />";
    }
}    
?>
```

Just used this

```
$url= trim($line);
```

worked fine.

**Problem solved.**

Comment: Could you explain what you are trying to achieve and what error or issue you are getting.

Comment: If you are going to ask for help then you should remove `@` operators. Hiding errors is not the way to figure out what the problem is.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it answers itself

Comment: No, the question didn’t answer itself. There was a problem understanding what’s going on, and just because using `trim` works, the author still doesn’t understand _why_ it works and _why_ the `trim` is necessary here in maybe in other similar situations. Therefore the question is still good.

Comment: The problem was that there was a space at each line, except the last one. So I figured I have to use trim, but I am terribly new to PHP (4weeks), so I wasn't aware of where to put the trim. Once I found out, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

When you enter a multi-line text in an HTML form, the lines are not separated by a single `\n` (as you expected) but by the two-character line end `\r\n`. Therefore you see an additional “space” in the HTML output. This is not a normal space like between words, but another line separator. But in displayed HTML they both look the same.

Doing a `trim` on the individual URLs is exactly the right thing to do.

---

And if the above guess should be incorrect, you should check whether the HTML form already contains these spaces when you enter them. And still, it is a good idea to trim the lines.

Comment: I checked for the spaces while entering, they just magicly appeared.